# Combine a matrix and its transpose to get a square symmetric matrix

Tags: r, matrix, data-manipulation

A matrix of a form such as,

```
structure(c("W1", NA, NA, NA, NA, "W1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "W2", 
NA, NA, "W2", NA, "W2", NA, NA, "W2", NA, NA, "W3", "W3", NA, 
NA, "W2", NA, NA, "W2", NA, NA, "W3", "W3", NA, NA, NA, "W3", 
"W3", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "W1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "W2", NA, NA, "W2", "W1", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "W1", NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(5L, 15L))

genmat



    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
[1,] "W1" "W1" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "W1"  NA    NA    NA    "W1"  "W1" 
[2,] NA   NA   "W2" "W2" NA   "W2" NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    "W2"  NA    NA   
[3,] NA   NA   NA   NA   "W3" NA   "W3" "W3" NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
[4,] NA   NA   NA   NA   "W3" NA   "W3" "W3" NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
[5,] NA   NA   "W2" "W2" NA   "W2" NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    "W2"  NA    NA
```

I want to combine this matrix and its transpose to get a square matrix of a form,

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
 [1,] "W1" "W1" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "W1"  NA    NA    NA    "W1"  "W1" 
 [2,] "W1" "W1" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "W1"  NA    NA    NA    "W1"  "W1" 
 [3,] NA   NA   "W2" "W2" NA   "W2" NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    "W2"  NA    NA   
 [4,] NA   NA   "W2" "W2" NA   "W2" NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    "W2"  NA    NA   
 [5,] NA   NA   NA   NA   "W3" NA   "W3" "W3" NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 [6,] NA   NA   "W2" "W2" NA   "W2" NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    "W2"  NA    NA   
 [7,] NA   NA   NA   NA   "W3" NA   "W3" "W3" NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 [8,] NA   NA   NA   NA   "W3" NA   "W3" "W3" NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 [9,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
[10,] "W1" "W1" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "W1"  NA    NA    NA    "W1"  "W1" 
[11,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
[12,] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
[13,] NA   NA   "W2" "W2" NA   "W2" NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    "W2"  NA    NA   
[14,] "W1" "W1" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "W1"  NA    NA    NA    "W1"  "W1" 
[15,] "W1" "W1" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "W1"  NA    NA    NA    "W1"  "W1"
```

This matrix is takes its elements from itersection of `genmat` and its transpose. i.e. the elements of output matrix at 1, 2, 10, 14 and 15 columns are same as corresponding columns of `genmat` and corresponding rows of transpose of `genmat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure I understood the question, but this seems to give the expected output:

```
genmat[apply(genmat, 2, function(col) match(TRUE, !is.na(col))), ]
```

What it does: for the `i`-th line of the result, use the `k`-th line of `genmat` where `k` is the index of the first non `NA` value of the `i`-th column of `genmat`.

In very explicit plain for-loops, that would look like:

```
res <- matrix(NA_character_, nrow = NCOL(genmat), ncol = NCOL(genmat))

for (i in seq_len(NROW(res))) {
  first_non_NA <- which(!is.na(genmat[, i]))[1]
  res[i, ] <- genmat[first_non_NA, ]
}
```

Note: this does not guarantee the symmetry of `res`. The symmetry comes from some non-explicit characteristic of your example data.